# Combining dataframes into a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm trying to store multiple dataframes in a list. However, at some point, the dataframes end up getting converted into lists, and so I end up with a list of lists.

All I'm really trying to do is keep all my dataframes together in some sort of structure.

Here's the code that fails:

```
all_dframes <- list() # initialise a list that will hold a dataframe as each item
for(file in filelist){ # load each file
    dframe <- read.csv(file) # read CSV file
    all_dframes[length(all_dframes)+1] <- dframe # add to the list
}
```

If I now call, for example, `class(all_dframes[1])`, I get 'list', whereas if I call `class(dframe)` I get 'data.frame'!

Comment: You could have done `files <- list.files(pattern=".csv"); lapply(files, function(x) read.csv(x, header=TRUE))`

Comment: Or `library(data.table); files <- lapply(list.files(pattern=".csv"), fread)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, the class of `all_dframes[1]` is `list` since `all_dframes` is a list. The function `[` returns a subset of the list. In this example, the length of the returned list is one. If you want to extract the data frame you have to use `[[`, i.e., `all_dframes[[1]]`.

Comment: Agk!  R's `[]`/`[[]]` distinction.  Hate it.  Thanks Sven.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest this:

```
library(data.table)
all_dframes <- vector("list",length(filelist))
for(i in 1:length(filelist)){ # load each file
       all_dframes[[i]]<-fread(filelist[i])
}
```

Is this what you need?