# How to Store Multiple Pandas DataFrames Together

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to store multiple pandas dataframes together in a collection of some sort - possibly a list, but since I want the list to be iterable such that **a column contained within a DataFrame within the list is accessible**, I've had trouble doing this. Found this this solution akin to my own problem, but the implementation is in R: [Combining dataframes into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730970/combining-dataframes-into-a-list)

```py
list = [pd.DataFrame() for i in range(k)]

for i in list:
    list[[i]].join(some_series)
```

Comment: Python lists do not use double brackets `[[` like R for indexing. Does that resolve your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python's lists and dictionaries can hold arbitrary objects, so there's nothing stopping you from storing a collection of DataFrames in either one:

3 DataFrames in a list:

```
In [33]: l = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((3,3)), columns=list('abc')) for _ in range(3)]

In [34]: l
Out[34]:
[          a         b         c
 0  0.169257  0.169213  0.424670
 1  0.341100  0.032424  0.662540
 2  0.065867  0.870850  0.283252,           
           a         b         c
 0  0.674488  0.945552  0.187434
 1  0.268596  0.990963  0.189113
 2  0.512963  0.525130  0.970127,           
           a         b         c
 0  0.775758  0.715841  0.213194
 1  0.400512  0.413347  0.115819
 2  0.725872  0.090014  0.354043]

In [35]: l[0]['c']
Out[35]:
0    0.424670
1    0.662540
2    0.283252
Name: c, dtype: float64
```

3 DataFrames in a dictionary:

```
In [36]: d = {c: pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((3,3)), columns=list('abc')) for c in 'xyz'}

In [37]: d['x']
Out[37]:
          a         b         c
0  0.438070  0.966919  0.782622
1  0.013869  0.141820  0.658972
2  0.730905  0.327317  0.156618

In [38]: d['x']['b']
Out[38]:
0    0.966919
1    0.141820
2    0.327317
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

If you're just looking to mash all the DataFrames together, you can use `pd.concat`, though that may result in some oddities if columns are duplicated or the DataFrames are differently shaped:

```
In [43]: big_df = pd.concat(l, axis=1)

In [44]: big_df
Out[44]:
          a         b         c         a         b         c         a         b         c
0  0.169257  0.169213  0.424670  0.674488  0.945552  0.187434  0.775758  0.715841  0.213194
1  0.341100  0.032424  0.662540  0.268596  0.990963  0.189113  0.400512  0.413347  0.115819
2  0.065867  0.870850  0.283252  0.512963  0.525130  0.970127  0.725872  0.090014  0.354043

In [45]: big_df['c']
Out[45]:
          c         c         c
0  0.424670  0.187434  0.213194
1  0.662540  0.189113  0.115819
2  0.283252  0.970127  0.354043
```

EDIT: To your comment, you can iterate over these in multiple ways:

Here's with a list comprehension:

```
In [189]: l = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((3,3)), columns=list('abc')) for _ in range(3)]

In [190]: [df['c'] for df in l]
Out[190]:
[0    0.919807
 1    0.342969
 2    0.181101
 Name: c, dtype: float64, 0    0.671494
 1    0.372866
 2    0.993980
 Name: c, dtype: float64, 0    0.384454
 1    0.556788
 2    0.998530
 Name: c, dtype: float64]

In [191]: pd.concat([df['c'] for df in l], axis=1)
Out[191]:
          c         c         c
0  0.919807  0.671494  0.384454
1  0.342969  0.372866  0.556788
2  0.181101  0.993980  0.998530
```

or just with a `for` loop:

```
In [192]: for df in l:
     ...:     print(df['b'])

0    0.372344
1    0.561873
2    0.386055
Name: b, dtype: float64
0    0.961725
1    0.942531
2    0.234676
Name: b, dtype: float64
0    0.029137
1    0.714375
2    0.856239
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

Comment: How would you iterate over the list of dataframes in a way that you can select the series from each one? Can you show an example of one with an iterator?

Comment: By any chance have you found a way?

Comment: @ProtimaRaniPaul There's examples of ways to iterate over the dataframes in my edit